# Makefile: sha256sum hangs forever with 0% CPU usage

Tags: makefile, rsync, sha

my Makefile behaves absolutely chaotically:

I have Makefile for backups. The backup directory has name format: `2023-09-11` and contains 3 disk image files, each with their sha256 checksum:

```
# ls -1 2023-09-11/
home.img
home.img.sha256
root.img
root.img.sha256
var.img
var.img.sha256
```

So basically, I first transfer the backup directory from usb disk, and then check if the checksums are correct:

Here is my makefile:

```
all: rsync shasum


rsync:
    @rsync -rt --delete /mnt/udisk/LAPTOP/ . 


shasum: home root var

home:
    @cd 20??-??-??/ && sha256sum -c home.img.sha256

root:
    @cd 20??-??-??/ && sha256sum -c root.img.sha256

var:
    @cd 20??-??-??/ && sha256sum -c var.img.sha256
```

when i run it, the `rsync` target completes successfully and fiels are transfered. However then the `shasum` target hangs in most bizarre way: it checks the first checksum `home` and prints OK. Then it hangs forever and nothin happens. `ps` does show the second target `sha256sum -c root.img.sha256` but with 0% CPU usage

```
0.0  0.0  /usr/bin/make
0.0  0.0     /bin/sh -c cd 20??-??-??/ && sha256sum -c root.img.sha256
0.0  0.0        sha256sum -c root.img.sha256
```

what is wrong with my Makefile?

Comment: that rsync deletes your Makefile if it is in `.`. How are you invoking `make` ?

Comment: btw, why three commands? you could just invoke a single command directly in the `shasum` rule. eg: `@cd 20??-??-??/ && sha256sum -c "$@".img.sha256`

Comment: if running on linux, you could invoke make under something like `strace -f -o /tmp/strace.log` to  try to see what the sha256sum is doing

Comment: Can't explain this.  In general it's a good idea to remove the `@` when debugging makefiles but that doesn't seem like it will help here.  If you run that same command from your shell prompt, outside of make, does it work?  You can also see what that command is doing by running `strace -p <pid>` (the <pid> of the `sha256sum` command)